# "Everyone" versus "everybody" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When can I use *everyone*, or *everybody* in a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the words mean "every person; all people." You can use one, or the other, depending on your preference; at the end, the sentence would not get a different meaning.

Comment: everyone's here?  
everybody's here?  
both words one mean?

Comment: The normal question is "Is anybody here?" You can also say "Is anyone here?" and the meaning doesn't change. The same is for "everybody is happy" and "everyone is happy."

Comment: @omid You can choose whichever sounds better to you in a particular sentence, but they're both fine.

Comment: @kiamlaluno "everyone's here?" would be asking a group if people if all the expected people have arrived or gathered.  The asker knows others are around.  "Is anyone here?" would be used if the asker is unsure if another person is in the area.  Not the same thing.

Comment: @Andy Actually, in Standard English a question as "Are you happy?" has a different meaning than "You are happy?" That is the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 3):

That's right. Both the words mean *every person*, but I think the word *everybody* is more informal.